# Custom Bone Property

Tags: python, rigging

I'm trying to add a custom property to a bone using python.  I think I can add the property using

```
bpy.types.PoseBone.customProp = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="customProp", default=0.0, min=0.0, max=1)
bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["BoneName"].customProp = 0.0
```

However, in the bone's 'Custom Properties' panel the property doesn't appear.
[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

##### Add Custom Properties to bone

```
bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["Bone"].bone["my_prop"] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you.  It definitely appears in OBJECT mode, but not in POSE mode.

Comment: Saving/Restarting Blender results in the property appearing btw